# Multiple queries asynchronously

Tags: ios, database, swift3, cloudkit

I need your opinion in which do you think are the best practices to do multiple queries to cloudkit.

I've an app that has a Main feed - I query this feed when the app launches and everything works perfectly, but I want to achieve , or at least understand how it's done in the, for example, Medium app for iOS for the bookmarks tab.

In the Medium app, after the first query in app launch if you click on the Bookmarks tab, all the posts are 'already there' so I assume they query that table asynchronously after the first query.

I thought that I could do a second query , after the first 'main' one, to the bookmarks table for the given user, and fill an array with those objects, then populate the table view as soon as the user clicks the tab.

My worries are on having an array, which main contain a lot of data and it's not used, and even could not be used for a good portion of the time during the app usage

Do you think that is a good practice or that I could achieve this on a different approach?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Take a look at section "Managing Dependent Tasks" on WWDC15 Session called CloudKit Tips and Tricks. In that section the speaker described the use of CloudKit operations. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/715/

Comment: Thanks Adolfo, I'll take a look :)